# About subdivision in homology (demonstration in Lee Introduction to Topological Manifolds, proposition 13.19)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

My question has to do with the following assetion given in *J.M. Lee: Introduction to Topological Manifolds, page 364*, in the context of demonstrating there exists a chain homotopy $h$ between the subdivision operator $s$ and $\mathcal{i}_p$, the identity in $\Delta_p$, defined by

$$h\sigma=\sigma_\#b_p*(\mathcal{i_p}-s\mathcal{i}_p-h\partial s\mathcal{i_p})$$

> Observe also that if $\sigma$ is a $\mathcal{U}$-small simplex, then $h\sigma$ is a $\mathcal{U}$-small chain, so $h$ maps $C_p^\mathcal{U}(X)$ to $C_{p+1}^\mathcal{U}(X)$

How can we actually be sure that is the case? I searched for an answer in *Glen E. Bredon: Topology and Geometry*, but I found nothing.

It would be interesting if anyone could give more insight to **what $h$ actually does** $-$geometrically speaking$-$, since the definition by recurrence doesn't offer any intuition at all

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are $\sigma_\#$ and $b_p$?

Comment: $\sigma$ is just any p-simplex $\sigma:\Delta_p\longrightarrow X$, and $\sigma_\#$ is the induced homomorphism between chain gruops $\sigma_\#:C_p(\Delta_p)\longrightarrow C_p(X)$

Comment: $b_p$ is the barycenter of $\Delta_p$; in other words, the point in $\text{Int}(\Delta_p)$ whose barycentric coordinated are all equal: $b_p=\sum_{i=0}^p \frac{1}{p+1}e_i$

Comment: You can prove it by induction, noting that $s$ maps simplices $\sigma$ on $\Delta$ to sums of simplices on $\Delta$ whose range is contained in the first barycentric subdivision of $\Delta.$ I find Lee's treatment of this wanting. At one point, he says something like "one can iterate $s$, to get $s^m$," without further comment, then cites a previous theorem, which does not seem to apply directly, to show that this implies that there is an integer $m$ for which $s^m \sigma$  maps into arbitrarily small subsets of $\Delta.$ I think Hatcher does all this more carefully.